# Rotación no funciona en Vue3 composition api

Tags: vue.js, vue3, composition-api

Estoy intentando hacer una rotación de una flecha cuando se hace click sobre ella, es el tipo ejemplo de menú desplegable,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
mi problema es que no consigo hacer que la flecha rote y que cambie de clase

Aqui esta mi componente

```
<template>
  <div>
    Sort by
    <div>
      <img
        @click="warnDisabled"
        :class="{ up: disabled, down: !disabled }"
        :src="icon_scan"
      />
    </div>

    <div class="filters-container">One</div>
    <div>Two</div>
    <div>Three</div>
    <div>Four</div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  import { useStore } from 'vuex'
  import { ref } from '@vue/reactivity'
  const disabled = ref(false)

  export default {
    props: {},
    name: 'SortByFilterCompoment',
    components: {},
    setup() {
      const store = useStore()
      return {
        icon_scan: require('../../assets/flecha-abajo-black.png'),
        warnDisabled
      }

      function warnDisabled() {
        console.log('VALUE BEFORE=>', disabled.value)

        if (!disabled.value) disabled.value = true
        else {
          disabled.value = false
        }
        console.log('VALUE AFTER=>', disabled.value)
      }
    }
  }
</script>

<style scoped lang="scss">
  .filters-container {
    display: grid;
  }
  .down {
    width: 10.65px;
    height: 5.32px;
    background-color: yellow;
    transition-duration: 0.8s;
    transition-property: transform;
    transform: rotate(360deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
  .up {
    width: 10.65px;
    height: 5.32px;
    background-color: red;
    transition-duration: 0.8s;
    transition-property: transform;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
</style>
```

la función  `warnDisabled()` se llama cada vez que se hace click sobre la flecha pero la animación no se lanza.

Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El Style Bindings de la imagen funciona con la variable `disabled`, la cual está declarando (estado reactivo) y setup no la está retornando.
Incluso su consola debería mostrar algo como: *[Vue warn]: Property "disabled" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance.*

Entendiendo esto solo siga:

```
setup() {
    return {
      warnDisabled,
      disabled,
    };
```